# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

This is a simple chat application project with Socket.io, but i am having problem connecting socket.io client which is in React to my server in Node

Connection code for **my server** is like this

```
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  }
})

const onSocketConnection = socket => {
    console.log('Socket connected')
    socketConnection(io, socket, db)
  }
  
  io.on("connection", onSocketConnection)
```

Connection in **client side** is like this

```
import io from "socket.io-client"
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000',{  
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5000",
        credentials: true
    },transports : ['websocket'] 
})
```

This is the error i am reviving

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJa39.png)

Comment: you create your sever at port 3000 and try to connect to port 8000. Maybe this is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

server side (http://localhost:8000):

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
...
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  }
})

// listening for connections from clients
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
  // listening to events from client
  socket.on('eventName', (params, callback) => {
     ...
    
    // send data back to client by using ack callback
    callback(data)

    // send data back to client by using emit
    socket.emit('eventName', data)

    // broadcasting data to all other connected clients
    socket.broadcast.emit('eventName', data)
  })  
})
```

client side (http://localhost:3000):

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client"
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000',{  
    withCredentials: true
})

// emit:
socket.emit('eventName', params, callback => {
  ...
})


// listen to events from sever:
socket.on('eventName', callback => {
  ...
})
```